# error recovery of ANTRL4 leaves loop

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I try to write a parser for subset of ABAP language. But I encounter some problems, when input contains misspelled/unknown statements.

In this example, one of the PERFORM statments is spelled PERFOR. So I expected parser to gobble tokens until re-sync, and proceed with follwing PERFORM statements.

```
 FUNCTION-POOL test.

 FUNCTION z_angebot_01.

  PERFORM x.

  LOOP AT mytable.

    PERFORM test.

    PERFOR test.

    PERFORM test.
    PERFORM test.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDFUNCTION.
```

Instead of this, the parser seems to try it with token insertion and leaves LOOP. Later it complains about extraneous ENDLOOP.

Output messages:
line 11:4 extraneous input 'PERFOR' expecting {ENDLOOP, LOOP_AT, PERFORM}
line 15:2 extraneous input 'ENDLOOP' expecting {ENDFUNCTION, LOOP_AT, PERFORM}

While debugging the generated code, I noticed, there is no error at all with PERFOR statement. The parser stays inside of loop as long as LOOP_AT or PERFORM is found. Anything else exits loop.
But how can i treat misspelled/unknown statements as syntax errors, which are to be ignored until next EOC token?

I use separated lexer/parser, so this is my current approach:

AbapLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar AbapLexer;

@lexer::header {
package generated;
}

WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
EOC     : '.' ;

ENDFUNCTION : [Ee][Nn][Dd][Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn];
ENDLOOP : [Ee][Nn][Dd][Ll][Oo][Oo][Pp];
FUNCTION : [Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn];
FUNCTION_POOL : [Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn] '-' [Pp][Oo][Oo][Ll];
LOOP_AT: [Ll][Oo][Oo][Pp] WHITESPACE [Aa][Tt];
PERFORM : [Pp][Ee][Rr][Ff][Oo][Rr][Mm];

IDENTIFIER: [_a-zA-Z] [_0-9a-zA-Z]* ;
fragment WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n]+;
```

AbapParser.g4:

```
parser grammar AbapParser;
options { tokenVocab=AbapLexer; }

@parser::header {
package generated;
}

report: (FUNCTION_POOL) IDENTIFIER EOC
        (functionStatement)*
        ; 

block:
(
    loopStatement EOC
|   performStatement EOC
)+
;

loopStatement:
    loopStatementStart EOC  
        block?
    ENDLOOP
;

loopStatementStart:
    LOOP_AT IDENTIFIER
;


performStatement:
    PERFORM IDENTIFIER
;

functionStatement
:
    FUNCTION functionname = IDENTIFIER EOC
    block?
    ENDFUNCTION EOC
;
```

Any hints appreciated!

Thank you

Peter

Comment: My guess is it fails to match the `block` and resumes at `ENDLOOP`. Not sure if it'll change anything but you could try the following: replace every instance of `block?` with `block`, and inside the `block` definition, replace the `+` quantifier with `*`, or try `block: ((performStatement|loopStatement) EOC)* ;`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! 
I tried your suggested changes. But there is no difference. In both cases I get same syntax tree ([link](http://www.peter-herweg.de/tree.png).

Comment: I added following rule  ... 

unknownStatement:
 ~(ENDLOOP|ENDFUNCTION) ~EOC*
; ... and added to block rule ...

Comment: ... so misspelled commands do not cause errors, but I get unknownStatement-nodes in syntax tree. After parsing i can user listener to check for those nodes.

Works for me, but if anyone has a better idea ... ?